# Specific text in txt file in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am making a "Who wants to be a millionare" game for my final c# project, and I have 15 txts with 3 questions/answers each. 
example:
`Whats the capital of Brasil? || Rio de Janeiro || Brasilia || Sao Paulo || Curitibia || Brasilia ||`

I want to store the question into an array[0,0], and the answers in the next positions [0,1 to 0,5] that's why there are the || to separate.
How to I do this for the 3 questions on every txt file?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please post some code of what you've done and what you've tried?

Comment: How are you doing it for one question in one text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a file that contains the questions and answers in the format you have given, here is an example you can enhance upon:

```
       string[] wordsArray = null;
       string s = string.Empty;
       string path = "file_1.txt";
       string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
       foreach (string aLine in lines)
       {
            s = aLine.Replace("||", "|");
            wordsArray = s.Split('|');
            //now you have the question in wordsArray[0], and the answers in the following
            //array cells ([1],[2], etc.)
            //You can do what you want here, including building a 2-d array using wordsArray.
       }
```

I am not sure why you use || instead of | or , and I am not sure why is the last answer delimited (this will create an empty cell in the above solution), you probably could go with something like:

Whats the capital of Brasil? | Rio de Janeiro | Brasilia | Sao Paulo | Curitibia | Brasilia